# Fastest way to load data

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have over 500 pieces of data (each containing 4 strings) which I want to load in my WindowsPhone application in several pages, using a ScrollViewer + Grid to display the information in TextBlocks. I thought of doing this with XML, but it didn't seem too appealing regarding speed. Is there a faster or officially preferred way to do this?

Comment: where is the data coming from?

Comment: Well it will come from a file in Local Storage on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although results can vary depending on the object graph being used, `Binary Serialization` is often a good way to go. The trade off is that it's not as versatile or easy to use, but you'll likely gain speed advantages. There's a [comparison table here](http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2010/12/windows-phone-7-serialization-comparison/) showing different types of serialization and deserialization.

Comment: SharpSerializer is awesome. The site keyboardP linked to has a pretty good example of using it in WP7.  http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2010/12/windows-phone-7-serialization-sharpserializer/

Answer (score 0):

Load the data into a collection of a custom type and use databinding.

Comment: Yes, but what is the fastest way to load the data?

Answer (score 0):

You might also look into [Marc Gravell's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) [port of Google's proto buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/), which has extremely impressive performance compared to the built in serialisation.